# Unable to download image as zip file using angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here i am having below dynamic data like this

```
data =  [
  "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff.jpg&text=test", 
  "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff.jpg&text=testOne",
  "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff.png&text=testTwo"
]
```

on button click i want to get the all the images from those url's and save it as zip

Issue : when ever i am able download the file as zip and try to extract it i am getting error as could not open image.zip as archieve and if i save as single image also the image is not opening up and is there any way to store the

below is my code

```
downloadImageData(){


  var blob = new Blob([this.data], { type:  'application/zip'' });

  FileSaver.saveAs(blob,'image.zip');

}
```

here i am having both png & jpg and various type of data so what ever data the links will get has to downloaded as zip file is there any approach for angular 5+. i am using filesave angular package also

JS ZIP _body resp

By using the http module im getting the below data [

```
  {
    "_body": {

    },
    "status": 200,
    "ok": true,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {
      "date": [
        "Sun",
        " 25 Nov 2018 12:18:47 GMT"
      ],
      "cache-control": [
        "public",
        " max-age=43200"
      ],
      "expires": [
        "Mon",
        " 26 Nov 2018 00:18:47 GMT"
      ],
      "content-disposition": [
        "attachment; filename=2B.JPG"
      ],
      "content-length": [
        "40649"
      ],
      "server": [
        "Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/2.7.13"
      ],
      "content-type": [
        "image/jpg"
      ]
    },
    "type": 2,
    "url": "http://some url"
  }
]
```

Comment: You have 3 `'` in `'application/zip'`, maybe it's an error from copying, but if you have it in your code then you should remove one

Comment: @ams That's typo error in application I have 2 only verified that

Comment: have you tried downloading the file without using FileSaver? For example with an a tag, I could provide an example if you want to.

Comment: If this is all your code, the problem is, that you have to download the binary data first. You cannot simply add an array of URLs and make it magically be a zip file by providing a content type. In angular you'd use the HttpClient to download the files.

Comment: @ams no i tried only using that as i thought it makes things simple & sure u can provide a sample by using the above urls

Comment: @ChristophLütjen by using htttp can we get ? & could  u help with a sample by using the above urls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little late, but this code will use your image array and create your GET requests. After that it will perform all requests and the responses will be added to your zip file and then downloaded.

I included two ways to download the file if you don't like to use the fileSaver. Pick whichever you prefer.

**EDIT:**

If you are using an old version of rxjs you'll have to import `forkJoin` in a different way, consult the rxjs documentation.
Also be sure that your backend allows the download of files, otherwise you'll have CORS errors.

[forkJoin Documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {

  data = [
    'http://yoururl/file.png',
    'http://yoururl/file2.png'
  ];

  getRequests = [];

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  download() {
    this.createGetRequets(this.data);

    forkJoin(...this.getRequests)
     .subscribe((res) => {
      const zip = new JSZip();

      res.forEach((f, i) => {
        zip.file(`image${i}.png`, f);
      });

      /* With file saver */
      // zip
      //   .generateAsync({ type: 'blob' })
      //   .then(blob => saveAs(blob, 'image.zip'));

      /* Without file saver */
      zip
        .generateAsync({ type: 'blob' })
        .then(blob => {
          const a: any = document.createElement('a');
          document.body.appendChild(a);

          a.style = 'display: none';
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          a.href = url;
          a.download = 'image.zip';
          a.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        });
     });
  }

  private createGetRequets(data: string[]) {
    data.forEach(url => this.getRequests.push(this._http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })));
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <button (click)="download()">Download</button>
</div>
```

I also had to include the path to jszip in my tsconfig.json. Depending on your version of angular you don't have to do this. Inside `"compilerOptions"` add following:

**tsconfig.json**

```
"paths": {
      "jszip": [
        "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"
      ]
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a solution with the old HttpModule, I tried it out and it works. I would suggest changing to the new HttpClientModule if possible.

**UPDATE2:**

Like I said in the comments, you can change the file extension when saving the file to handle different file types. This is an example and you can easily expand this solution.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, ResponseContentType } from "@angular/http"; // Different Import
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";
import * as JSZip from "jszip";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {

  /* 
    UPDATE 2
    Create a Type map to handle differnet file types 
  */
  readonly MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
    "image/png": "png",
    "image/jpeg": "jpg",
    "image/jpg": "jpg",
    "image/gif": "gif"
  };

  data = [
    "http://url/file.png",
    "http://url/file.jpeg",
    "http://url/file.gif"
  ];

  getRequests = [];

  constructor(private _http: Http) {} // Different Constructor

  download() {
    this.createGetRequets(this.data);

    forkJoin(...this.getRequests).subscribe(res => {
      const zip = new JSZip();
      console.log(res);
      /*
        The return value is different when using the HttpModule.
        Now you need do access the body of the response with ._body,
        as you can see inside the forEach loop => f._body
      */
      let fileExt: String;  // UPDATE 2

      res.forEach((f, i) => {
        fileExt = this.MIME_TYPE_MAP[f._body.type]; // UPDATE 2, retrieve type from the response.
        zip.file(`image${i}.${fileExt}`, f._body);  // UPDATE 2, append the file extension when saving
      });

      zip
        .generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
        .then(blob => saveAs(blob, "image.zip"));
    });
  }

  private createGetRequets(data: string[]) {
    /*
      Change your responseType to ResponseContentType.Blob
    */
    data.forEach(url =>
      this.getRequests.push(
        this._http.get(url, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE3:**

Solution which extracts the file name from the URL, this way the file type is not needed:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, ResponseContentType } from "@angular/http";
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";
import * as JSZip from "jszip";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = ["http://url/file.png", "http://url/file.jpg", "http://url/file.gif"];

  getRequests = [];

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  download() {
    this.createGetRequets(this.data);

    forkJoin(...this.getRequests).subscribe(res => {
      const zip = new JSZip();
      let fileName: String;

      res.forEach((f, i) => {
        fileName = f.url.substring(f.url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); // extract filename from the response
        zip.file(`${fileName}`, f._body); // use it as name, this way we don't need the file type anymore
      });

      zip
        .generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
        .then(blob => saveAs(blob, "image.zip"));
    });
  }

  private createGetRequets(data: string[]) {
    data.forEach(url =>
      this.getRequests.push(
        this._http.get(url, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can we use using http request bcoz my existing project already using http request so if I put http client module then it will give error I think right

Comment: @Madpop I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean, can you be a little more specific? Inside `download()`. `createGetRequest` will create your requests from your image array and push them inside `getRequests` . This array will then be passed to `forkJoin()`. `forkJoin` will perform your requests, it works similar to `Promise.all()`.

Comment: @Madpop Give me a second I'll try it out

Comment: ok http module I'm using so if I put http client module then both will have conflict

Comment: @Madpop Yes, you shouldn't use both, choose one. The old HttpModule is deprecated, that's why I suggested to use the new HttpClientModule. Did my solution work for you?

Comment: could u post the old http solution also

Comment: @Madpop I posted both solutione... The one with HttpModule is in the updated section.

Comment: there is one issue here with mentioning the file type is it possible bcoz i may l load various format of images in code mentioned as zip.file(`image${i}.png`, f._body); so there i got the issue

Comment: @Madpop `images${i}.png` is just a string, you can name your file however you want to. you could for example extract the file type from the response and add the file extension to the name according to it. e.g. `images${i}.${fileExt}`. If possible create a simple version of your program on stackBlitz, so that it's easier to help you out.

Comment: yeah i will create it and post it shortly

Comment: please check the url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qhuvb    although stackblitz is not executing and displaying error using in jszip and file-saver

Comment: if i am uploading .jpg,.png,.jpeg then after file download it is showing it as .png and we are not getting the original file types

Comment: @Madpop I added a solution for different file types. Like I said, just append the correct file extension when saving the file.

Comment: just a small doubt how can i get the origianl image names ? in body it is not there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184260/discussion-between-madpop-and-ams).

Answer (score 4):

I have created a demo application [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjpjeb).

P.S: The code is for guidance only, and may not include standard coding practices but  may guide you to create your own version of the solution.

I'm using [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) to zip file.

**app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpClientModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<button (click)='downloadZip()'>Download</button>`
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  downloadZip() {
    this.loadSvgData("https://c.staticblitz.com/assets/client/icons/file-icons/angular-component-31179578a9a8a16512e9e90ade26549a.svg",
    this.saveAsZip);
  }

  private loadSvgData(url: string, callback: Function) : void{
    this.http.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })
             .subscribe(x => callback(x));
  }

  private saveAsZip(content: Blob) : void{
    var zip = new JSZip.default();
    zip.file("image.svg", content);
    zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
       .then(blob => saveAs(blob,'image.zip'));
  };
}
```

**Explanation:**

The application only has one button, which on click will download an image file from the server using `HttpClient`. It will zip downloaded data using `jszip`and save it to browser using `file-saver`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: can use http also  instead of httpClient  & i have a array of images ?

Comment: in the code u mentioned zip.file("image.svg", content); say i dont know the conten type either jpg or png or text then ?

Comment: @Madpop You need to know name of the file, if not then you at-least need to parse url to determine extension of the file (technically, you can add the file without extension but then user will have to know editor which can open the file).

Comment: @Madpop, you can modify callback function so that it will wait for all files to be downloaded before zipping them. BTW, which version of angular are you using?